# 4clojure #58 (compose)... stuck

Tags: clojure

trying to do compose (#58)

```
(defn compose [& fns]
  (fn [a & opts]
    (if opts
      ;println can be removed, just shows my confusion
      (reduce (fn [x y] (println(apply y (list x))) (apply y (list x))) (cons a opts) (reverse fns)))
      (reduce (fn [x y] (y x)) a (reverse fns))))

((compose rest reverse) 1 2 3 4)
```

I've killed too much time on this so I'm resorting to asking for help... I've only got about 2-3 days experience so forgive the ugly clojure and the most likely unnecessary if form.  I'd like to know what is wrong with this, as opposed to getting a completely different (and I'm sure nicer) answer.

What's confusing me is that the error is indicating I am trying to call a list as a function, but the print statement is showing exactly the results I would expect, using the same code as the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just got your parens in the wrong place. This works:

```
(defn compose [& fns]
  (fn [a & opts]
    (if opts
      (reduce (fn [x y] (apply y (list x))) (cons a opts) (reverse fns))
      (reduce (fn [x y] (y x)) a (reverse fns)))))
```

It was easy for me to see the problem right away because I use an editor that understands about parens and alignment - I just put your code in IntelliJ/Cursive. Cursive uses structural editing (otherwise known as Paredit).

Also when debugging be aware that `println` returns nil. I often use a probe function for this kind of debugging:

```
(defn probe-on
  ([x]
   (println x)
   x)
  ([x msg]
   (println msg x)
   x))
```

, but you can now (or coming, they are still a little new) get editors/debuggers that don't require you to use such debugging techniques. See proto-REPL and Sayid.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I don't think parens were the issue.  Also, I only intended to use apply once, the println was just to show that the printed representation of the same function call I'm using in the body of the function returns what I want, yet the actual body does not.  This function (as well as the edited one above) fail in a test case where multiple arguments are passed (test case 3 in 4clojure #58, for example)

Comment: I just used your code as is and got the error `IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:547)`. Then I removed the `println` and aligned the parens. Then instead of the error I got the correct result of `(3 2 1)`. I didn't look at the logic of your code. I got rid of your confusing error, which seemed to be the main point of your question.

Comment: fair enough.. since you technically answered the question that was asked I'm accepting this, but for the benefit of any future viewers.. the function is broken in the event the composed function expects multiple arguments (e.g. +), because i'm first converting to a nested list and then trying to apply the function to that list as opposed to the individual arguments

Comment: I took away the extra apply to avoid confusion. Now you've got me trying to solve it too. Sounds like you've already solved it. I'll come back to your comment if I get really stuck!

Comment: I figured out my problem... but I had to get a little extra "inspiration" from the internet to help solve it ;)  I was close before adding the if statement in!

Comment: This: `(apply y (if (seq? x) x (list x)))` get me past the third test, but I think you must have done something better to get past the forth as well. Any hints?

Comment: If you're still working on it... think about the fact that only the final function (rightmost) needs to accept multiple arguments, all the others accept only one.  Then you can treat the last function as a special case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144000/discussion-between-chris-murphy-and-solaxun).